# what is the case of replay attack for which OIDC nonce is a protection

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, nonce

In the context of user authentication using OIDC/OAuth 2 with Authorization Code + PKCE in a web-based Single Page Application (SPA), a nonce parameter can be generated and sent to the identity provider to mitigate replay attacks.

https://oa.dnc.global/-OpenID-Connect-Autorisation-via-un-code-Authorization-Code-Flow-.html

While the nonce parameter is mandatory for the now-obsolete implicit flow, it's optional for the authorization code flow.

What are the potential attack vectors if the nonce parameter is not used?

The SPA can validate that the ID token is invalid if the nonce claim in the JWT doesn't match, but when an attacker can send a valid but stolen ID token to the SPA?

Answer (score 2):

TLDR;

`nonce` is meant to provide protection against [authorization code injection attacks](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics#name-authorization-code-injectio), BUT it doesn't provide this protection in the case of public clients, e.g., SPA's.

---

For an explanation of what protection the `nonce` parameter provides, have a look here:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics#nonce_as_injection_protection

The last paragraph addresses your question with regard to what protection `nonce` provides specifically for public clients, e.g., SPAs:

> It is important to note that nonce does not protect authorization codes of public clients, as an attacker does not need to execute an authorization code injection attack. Instead, an attacker can directly call the token endpoint with the stolen authorization code.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics#section-4.5.3.2-4

---

The following section then addresses the next concern, i.e., "If the `nonce` parameter doesn't provide protection for public clients, then what should I use? "

> PKCE is the most obvious solution for OAuth clients as it is available today (originally intended for OAuth native apps) whereas nonce is appropriate for OpenID Connect clients.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics#section-4.5.3.3-2

---

Now, if you're asking what the difference between PKCE and `nonce` is and why PKCE can protect public clients while `nonce` cannot, the difference is the different steps of the OAuth/OIDC flow where they come into play.

The nonce is generated by the client and sent in with the authorization request similar to how the `code_challenge` and `code_challenge_method` (optionally) in PKCE. The OP stores the value(s) and returns the `authorization code`. However, what follows differs.

Using `nonce`:

- The client sends the `authorization code` to the OP.
- The OP puts the `nonce` received in the authorization request into the (`ID`) token and returns the token
- **The client checks the `nonce` value in the token with the value in session storage**

Using PKCE:

- The clients sends the `authorization code` **AND** the `code_verifier` to the OP
- **The OP checks the `code_verifier` by transforming it with the `code_challenge_method` and checking if it matches the `code_challenge` received previously.**
- The OP returns the token(s).

I bolded the steps where the "protection occurs" for each. Using `nonce` the burden is more on the client to verify the `nonce` value in the token matches what it created and stored earlier. With PKCE, the OP does the work with the `code_verifier` transformation and compares it to the earlier `code_challenge`.

If a malicious client is able to steal the authorization code, there is no protection against that client getting a token and using it. It doesn't have to check the `nonce` parameter. It doesn't care. But, with PKCE, the malicious client needs to have the `code_verifier` or the OP will not return a token.

Comment: thanks a lot to have take the time for a clear and detailed response ;-)

Comment: No problem! Happy I could help.